# Multicast hostname lookups on OSX

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, ipv6, multicast, ipv4

I have a problem with hostname lookups on my OSX computer. According to Apple's [HK3473](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3473) document it says for v10.6:

> Host names that contain only one label in addition to local, for example "My-Computer.local", are resolved using Multicast DNS (Bonjour) by default. Host names that contain two or more labels in addition to local, for example "server.domain.local", are resolved using a DNS server by default.

Which is not true as my testing. If I try to open a connection on my local computer to a remote port:

```
telnet example.domain.local 22
```

then it will lookup the IP address with *multicast DNS* next to the `A` and `AAAA` lookups. This causes a two seconds lookup timeout on every lookup. Which is a lot!

When I try with IPv4 only then it won't use the multicast queries to fetch the remote address just the simple `A` queries.

```
telnet -4 example.domain.local 22
```

When I try with IPv6 only:

```
telnet -6 example.domain.local 22
```

then it will lookup with multicast DNS *and* `AAAA` again, and the 2 seconds timeout delay occurs again.

I've tried to create a resolver entry to my `/etc/resolver/domain.local`, and `/etc/resolver/local.1`, but none of them was working.

Is there any way to disable this multicast lookups for the "two or more label addition to local" domains, or simply disable it for the selected subdomain (domain.local)?

Thank you!

*Update #1*

Thanks @mralexgray for the `scutil --dns` command, now I can see my domain in the list, but it's late in the order:

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  domain : adverticum.lan
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.1.1
  order   : 200000

resolver #2
  domain : local
  options : mdns
  timeout : 2
  order   : 300000

resolver #3
  domain : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options : mdns
  timeout : 2
  order   : 300200

resolver #4
  domain : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options : mdns
  timeout : 2
  order   : 300400

resolver #5
  domain : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options : mdns
  timeout : 2
  order   : 300600

resolver #6
  domain : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options : mdns
  timeout : 2
  order   : 300800

resolver #7
  domain : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options : mdns
  timeout : 2
  order   : 301000

resolver #8
  domain : domain.local
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.1.1
  order   : 200001
```

Maybe it would work if I could move the `resolver #8` to the position #2.

*Update #2*

No probably won't work because the local DNS server on `192.168.1.1` answering for `domain.local` requests and it's before the mDNS (`resolver #2`).

*Update #3*

I could decrease the mDNS timeout in `/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/IPMonitor.bundle/Contents/Info.plist` file, which speeds up the lookups a little, but this is not the solution.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? Disabling mDNSResponder actually broke all applications that resolved hostnames (Safari, Finder etc)

Comment: No, unfortunately not yet :(

Comment: Looking at the order: field I think your resolver is already the 2nd one.

Comment: Yes, the `scutil` says that, but the resolution is working differently!

Answer (score 1):

Have you  tried defining the names in your `/etc/hosts` file?

```
10.0.1.1                ns1 ns1.local
10.0.1.200              www www.local
2001:470:20::9999       www ns1 www.example.net ns1.example.net
```

What other DNS services are operating on the local subnet?  You can resolve a lot of issues by serving local DNS explicitly, and quite simply - with [DNSMasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html), which I whole-heartedly recommend doing.

You also may simply need to flush things out with a `dscacheutil -flushcache` ↩ or a good ole `sudo killall mDNSResponder` ↩. On the extreme end of things, which I don't suggest - you can also disable mDNSResponder (Bonjour, etc) alltogether  ↝

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponderHelper.plist
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
```

Post-10.5 systems provide DNS resolution via a pretty confusing chain of directives, mandated by **configd**, heir-apparent to the old "system kicker".  To get its status ↝ `scutil --dns` ↩ which shows the system order of DNS resolution, such as ↯

> DNS configuration
>
> resolver #1   domain: example.net  search domain[0]: example.net  nameserver[0]: 127.0.0.1   order: 200000
>
> resolver #2   domain: local   options: mdns   timeout: 2   order: 300000
>
> resolver #3   domain:254.169.in-addr.arpa   options: mdns   timeout: 2   order: 300200
>
> resolver #4   domain: 8.e.f.ip6.arpa  options: mdns   timeout: 2   order: 300400

If you're still having problems, make sure this list "makes sense, for you" - and go from there...

Comment: I could not set the addresses in my `/etc/hosts` file, because they are in the company's DNS.

Comment: FYI if I set an example host in my hosts file, it works and does not send mDNS requests.

Comment: what do you get from entering _scutil --dns_?  and how about showing a dig or nslookup that isn't working for you...

Comment: I've already pasted my `sciutil --dns` output to the question. (See Update). The problem is not that, that `nslookup` or `dig` is not working. But a simple lookup at `telnet` or Safari opening a `domain.local` ending page takes too much time because of mDNS lookup.

Comment: on recent systems (10.6 and later for sure, maybe older), if you disable mDNSResponder you will lose all domain lookups.